# How to programmatically get iOS's alphanumeric version string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been working with the nice [PLCrashReport](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) framework to send to my server the crash reports from my user's iOS devices.

However, to symbolicate the crash report, the **symbolicatecrash** utility requests that along with the iPhone OS version number, I have the ipsw's alphanumeric version, in the form of:

```
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.1 (8A293)
```

I know that I can get the iOS's numeric version by `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`, but how can I get the other one?

I can't find a way, and I've searched everywhere I could imagine.

Comment: For the record, that string is the build number.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not sure why others are saying that this is not possible because it is using the `sysctl` function.

```
#import <sys/sysctl.h>    

- (NSString *)osVersionBuild {
    int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_OSVERSION};
    u_int namelen = sizeof(mib) / sizeof(mib[0]);
    size_t bufferSize = 0;

    NSString *osBuildVersion = nil;

    // Get the size for the buffer
    sysctl(mib, namelen, NULL, &bufferSize, NULL, 0);

    u_char buildBuffer[bufferSize];
    int result = sysctl(mib, namelen, buildBuffer, &bufferSize, NULL, 0);

    if (result >= 0) {
        osBuildVersion = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buildBuffer length:bufferSize encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]; 
    }

    return osBuildVersion;   
}
```

Comment: Dylan, what values do you use for CTL_KERN and KERN_OSVERSION in iOS?

Comment: Those two values are defined in `sys/sysctl.h`.

Comment: This is helpful, but what about the version *number*, i.e. 3.1.3 or 4.2.1?

Comment: Jason, if you want to get the version number you can directly access `systemVersion ` property on a `UIDevice` instance.

Comment: altering "return osBuildVersion;" line to "return [osBuildVersion stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@""];" helped me  for NSString end-line problem, that i had.

Comment: As written this includes the null "\0" character that ends strings in C. The correct way to deal with this is to use the NSString initializer "initWithCString" instead of "initWithBytes".

Answer (score 9):

Why don´t you try this?

```
NSString *os_version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];

NSLog(@"%@", os_version);

if([[NSNumber numberWithChar:[os_version characterAtIndex:0]] intValue]>=4) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This would fail when iOS goes to version 10 and beyond, up to version 39? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I've reached here looking for an answer to how to do this in Swift and, after some test and error, just found that you can write this, at least in Xcode 9:

```
print(ProcessInfo().operatingSystemVersionString)
```

And the output I get in simulator is:

```
Version 11.0 (Build 15A5278f)
```

And in a real device:

```
Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had problems uploading Dylan's string to a PHP web server, the URL connection would just hang, so I modified the code as follows to fix it:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

    - (NSString *)osVersionBuild {
        int mib[2] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_OSVERSION};
        size_t size = 0;

        // Get the size for the buffer
        sysctl(mib, 2, NULL, &size, NULL, 0);

        char *answer = malloc(size);
        int result = sysctl(mib, 2, answer, &size, NULL, 0);

        NSString *results = [NSString stringWithCString:answer encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        free(answer);
        return results;  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this result. I think the original solution posted above only works for iOS4 and below.

Comment: @npellow, the original solution is working fine on my 4S with 5.0.1

Comment: Unused variable `result`

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this (at least, not in UIKit).  Please [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) requesting it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'other one' is the build version, and isn't available to your device through UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of @Dylan Copeland answer.

```
func systemBuild() -> String? {
    var mib: [Int32] = [CTL_KERN, KERN_OSVERSION]
    let namelen = u_int(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: mib) / MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: mib[0]))
    var bufferSize: size_t = 0
    
    // Get the size for the buffer
    sysctl(&mib, namelen, nil, &bufferSize, nil, 0)
    
    var buildBuffer: [u_char] = .init(repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
    
    let result = sysctl(&mib, namelen, &buildBuffer, &bufferSize, nil, 0)
    
    if result >= 0 && bufferSize > 0 {
        return String(bytesNoCopy: &buildBuffer, length: bufferSize - 1, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false)
    }
    
    return nil
}
```