# Version Number of Smartphone OS's

Tags: javascript, android, ios, regex, blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically get iOS’s alphanumeric version string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857195/how-to-programmatically-get-ioss-alphanumeric-version-string)

Is there any future proof regex to get the version number of the following smartphone OS's from the user-agent?

**Android**

(I have found something like: /Androids+([d.]+)/ )

**iOS**

**BlackBerry**

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Clarification: Seems like the question is asking how to get the mobile device OS version in a web-app, probably using JS.

UPDATE:

After I got quite bashed to ask this question I want at least provide the solution I came up with:

```
supportedDevice: function() {
    var supportedDevice = false;
    var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;

    // check for supported Android device
    if ( /Android/.test(userAgent) ) {
        var a_index = Number(userAgent.indexOf('Android')) + 8;
        var a_version = +userAgent.substring(a_index, a_index+1);
        if ( a_version >= 3 ) {
            supportedDevice = true;
            console.log('Android device supported!')
        }

    }
    // check for iOS supported devices
    else if ( /iPhone/.test(userAgent) ) {
        var i_index = Number(userAgent.indexOf('iPhone OS')) + 10;
        var i_version = +userAgent.substring(i_index, i_index+1);
        if ( i_version >= 6 ) {
            supportedDevice = true;
            console.log('iPhone device supported!')
        }
    }
    // check for iOS supported devices
    else if ( /BlackBerry/.test(userAgent) ) {
        var b_index = Number(userAgent.indexOf('Version/')) + 8;
        var b_version = +userAgent.substring(b_index, b_index+1);
        if ( b_version >= 6 ) {
            supportedDevice = true;
            console.log('BB device supported!')
        }
    }
    return supportedDevice;
}
```

Comment: You don't typically just use a regex to get a version number; you would probably use a platform-specific method to get that number.

Comment: How do you use a platform-specific  method from a mobile web app just developed with open standards like HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript?

Comment: provide what is the input you see from the programming language end. Ex: IOS 5.2.1 etc.,

Comment: He wants to parse the user agent header sent by mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to obtain the version number in a web app, your best bet would be to use the device User Agent and parse out the version number. A more robust method would be to look up the user agent in the [WURFL database](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) to obtain the device characteristics and the corresponding OS. The first method is simpler.

If you are using an app, most OS SDKs provide APIs to identify the version of the OS running on the device