# How to get the system version build of iOS device like 14D27 for iOS 10.2.1

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get the system version build of an iOS device like "14D27" for iOS 10.2.1?

Not:

```
UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

I know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This alphanumeric string is the *build number*, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5462277/4763963) explains a way to get it. Good luck!

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, flag it as such.  Don't answer it